# How to remove two equal adjacent numbers in SWI-PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I am new in PROLOG and having a difficulty to achieve few taskes. It could have been great if someone can help me in this regard. So this is the idea:

I have a list of numbers which contains `[3413242341]` and goal is simplifying this list till i can have an empty list `[]`. (numbers simplification tech). i broked down the objectives as below:

1. Predicates initialisation.
2. (R1)If two adjacent numbers are equal, program should remove both of them.
3. (R2)Program should be able to switch between two adjacent digits if the absolute value of their    difference is greater than 1.
4. (R3)(n, n-1, n) sequence must be able to be replaced by the (n-1, n, n-1) sequence.

it's been two days which i am struggling with this program, any helps will be highly appriciated.

Comment: `[3413242341]` is a list with exactly one element, the number 3413242341

Comment: What is "predicate initialisation" where do you have this from?

Comment: Where are test cases? In two days you certainly have produced some of them.

Comment: How do the rules interact? What if two rules clash, for instance rule `R3` can clash with `R1`...

Comment: @CommuSoft As I understand the goal is to find the sequence of steps for bringing the initial list to an empty list using the rules.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Sure, but say you have a list with `[4,3,4]`, what do you first? `(R1)` remove adjecents thus `[4]` or `(R3)` `[3,4,3]`? Or is it the aim to find the sequence of rules to apply?

Comment: @CommuSoft Well, just speculating, but I think it's a search problem. The goal is to find the path from start point to the final goal. Either minimal or any. It's up to algorithm to decide.

Answer (score 0):

The big deal with prolog is that it is a *declarative language*: you describe the solution in terms of the *predicate calculus* and let the prolog inference engine figure out the solution. Often a prolog program will look an awful lot like the problem statement. Let's start shall we?

Your problem statement describes 2 specific rules and has (IMHO) a 3rd, implied rule:

- Two adjacent, identical numbers are removed completely (`[1,2,2,3]` → `[1,3]`).
- The sequence N,N-1,N is swapped (`[8,5,4,5,9]` → `[8,4,5,4,9]`).
- And (implied) is that any thing else is unchanged.

That would suggest a solution something like this:

```
reduce( []         , []         ).                               % When the source list is exhausted, we're done.
reduce( [N,N|Ns]   , Rs         ) :-             reduce(Ns,Rs) . % Apply Rule #1
reduce( [N,Q,N|Ns] , [Q,N,Q|Rs] ) :- Q =:= N-1 , reduce(Ns,Rs) . % Apply Rule #2
reduce( [N|Ns]     , [N|Rs]     ) :-             reduce(Ns,Rs) . % Apply Rule #3: (implied)
```

I don't know, of course, if this meets your requirements. Another approach might be something like this:

```
reduce( []     ) .       % The empty list is the desired state
reduce( [N|Ns] ) :-      % otherwise ...
  remove_pairs(Ns,T1) ,  % - apply rule #1 to the entire list  
  do_swaps(T2,T3) ,      % - apply rule #2 to the entire list
  T3 \= [N|Ns] ,         % - if something changed
  reduce( T3 )           % - repeat the exercise with the changed list
  .                      % Easy!

%
% apply Rule #1 to the entire list:
% Remove adjacent pairs such that [1,2,2,3] -> [1,3]
%
remove_pairs( []       , []     ) .
remove_pairs( [X]      , [X]    ) .
remove_pairs( [X,X|Xs] ,    Rs  ) :-          remove_pairs(Ns,Rs) .
remove_pairs( [X,Y|Xs] , [X|Rs] ) :- X \= Y , remove_pairs(Xs,Rs) .

%
% Apply Rule #2 to the entire list:
% Swap N,Q,N where Q is N-1 such that [8,5,4,5,9] -> [8,4,5,4,9]
%
do_swaps( []         , []         ) .
do_swaps( [N]        , [N]        ) .
do_swaps( [N,Q]      , [N,Q]      ) .
do_swaps( [N,Q,N|Ns] , [Q,N,Q|Rs] ) :- Q =:= N-1 , do_swaps(Ns,Rs) .
do_swaps( [N,Q,N|Ns] , [N,Q,N|Rs] ) :- Q =\= N-1 , do_swaps(Ns,Rs) .
```

This applies each transform to the entire list. If the list changed, we recursively apply the `reduce/1` operation, which will succeed if the list is eventually transformed into the empty list `[]` and ultimately fail when the transforms fails to make any changes.

On backtracking, of course, it will attempt to find another solution.

Comment: Dear NICHOLAS CAREY,Firstly i need to say a HUGE thanks for your support and your really helpful tips and remarks. You made it way easier for me to understand. But could you please tell me in more detail the exact difference between the first solution and the second one? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the exercice :

```
simplify(In, Lst) :-
    simplify(In, [], [], Lst).


simplify([], _Deja_vu, RL, L) :- !, reverse(RL, L).
simplify(In,  Deja_vu, Cur, Lst) :-
    (   r1(In, Out), L =r1; r2(In, Out), L = r2; r3(In, Out), L=r3),
    % we must avoid cycles
    \+member(Out, Deja_vu),
    simplify(Out, [Out| Deja_vu],[L|Cur], Lst).

% If two adjacent numbers are equal, program should remove both of them.
r1(In, Out) :-
    append(L, [X,X|T], In),
    append(L, T, Out).

% switch between two adjacent digits if the absolute value of
% their difference is greater than 1.
r2(In, Out) :-
    append(L, [X,Y|T], In),
    abs(X-Y) > 1,
    append(L, [Y,X|T], Out).

% (n, n-1, n) sequence must be able to be replaced by the (n-1, n, n-1) sequence.
r3(In, Out) :-
    append(L, [X,Y, X|T], In),
    X =:= Y+1,
    append(L, [Y,X,Y|T], Out).
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch JOEL76, could you please guide me to do the case test in SWI-PROLOG? thanks in advance

Comment: I use SWi-Prolog, you just have to try **simplify([3,4,1,3,2,4,2,3,4,1], L)**

Comment: Thanks for your response, but after trying it on SWI-Prolog. program has been stuck in a infinite loop. the result is as  below L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] ;
L = [r2, r2, r2, r1, r2, r2, r2, r2, r2|...] .......... And so on. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Yes, there is a great number of solutions.

Comment: I have a little question for you, the aim was simplifying a search method on the list of numbers in order to have the empty list at the end(ideal state).As we saw, it's not very clear to say when it's going to happen. I really appreciate if you can explain it to me more detailed. Thanks in advance.